# POST data from android using Volley to Laravel5

Tags: php, android, laravel-5

I'm having problems on what URL to be used to link to the php scripts in Laravel5 which I'm running at localhost at the moment. I have created a function in my controller to handle the request. Here is the function:

```
    public function mobile_validator(Request $request) {
    $method = $request->method();
    if($method == 'POST') {
        $username = $request->username;
        $password = $request->password;
        $user = DB::table('users')->get();
        foreach($user as $i) {
            if($username == $i->email and $password == $i->password) {
                return 'success';
            }
            else {
                return 'failure';
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also created a route in my route.php.

```
Route::get('/mobilevalidator', 'AuthController@mobile_validator');
```

This is my URL in android:

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/mobilevalidator/";
```

Now when I login in my app it displays the error com.android.volley.timeouterror

Is the URL correct in defining the php script in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes you defined a

```
Route::get
```

That means that this route is listening to the GET method. In your controller you specify

```
$method = $request->method();
if($method == 'POST') {
```

Which means your controller is actually only returning stuff you have a POST which will ofcourse never happen since your route calling your controller is only listening to GET

You can complety remove the check of the method. A controller method can only be called if you map the route to it. If you want to also support POST simply add

```
Route::post( ... )
```

A little hint:

Try to use PostMan or any other RestClient to test your Routes before using them in your app. Also don't forget to remove the web middleware in laravel - otherwise you will also need to add the csrf token to your request.